# Multiple conditions in SSRS expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I know how to use SSRS expression when there is a single condition.

```
=iif(fields!Type.value='Invoce', 'Red','Black')
```

But how to write it if there are several conditions, for example

```
if Type=invoce type=Purchse Return, Type=Sales Return
```

and i need to give different colours for all.

Thanks

Comment: Use nested iif. So on the false clause, write another iif()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IIF:**

> =IIF(fields!Type.value = "Invoice1", "LightBlue", **IIF(fields!Type.value = "Invoice2", "Plum"**,
>   IIF(fields!Type.value="Invoice3", "Orange", "Aqua")**)**)

**SWITCH:**

> =SWITCH(Fields!id.Value = "Invoice1", "LightBlue", **Fields!id.Value = "Invoice2","Plum"**, Fields!id.Value = "Invoice3","Orange", TRUE,
>   "Aqua")